# How is the t-distribution a statistic considering it is dependent on parameter mu?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Casella and Berger textbook teaches that a statistic is only the function of a random sample and never its unknown population parameter(s).

In the case of Student's t-distribution, while it utilizes the sample variance in place of the unknown variance population parameter, its distribution still relies on the mean mu population parameter.

Shouldn't this disqualify Student's t-distribution as being a statistic?

Thanks for any information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing a number of concepts.  A $t$-distribution is a probability distribution.  If a random variable $T$ is Student's $t$-distributed with $\nu$ degrees of freedom, then it has density
$$f_T(t) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{\nu + 1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) \sqrt{\nu}} \left(\frac{\nu}{t^2 + \nu}\right)^{(\nu + 1)/2}, \quad -\infty < t < \infty.$$
On the other hand, if we have a **sample** from a **normally** distributed population $\boldsymbol X = (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$  with $$X_i \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu, \sigma^2), \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$$ independent and identically distributed, then the **pivotal quantity**
$$T = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}$$ is Student's $t$-distributed with $\nu = n-1$ degrees of freedom.  When $\mu$ is unknown, then indeed $T$ is not a statistic.  However, this quantity is used in the context of hypothesis testing; e.g., for a test of location of the form $$H_0 : \mu = \mu_0 \quad \text{vs.} \quad H_1 : \mu \ne \mu_0,$$ the **test statistic** $$T \mid H_0 = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}} \sim \operatorname{StudentT}(n-1)$$ is in fact a statistic and is Student's $t$-distributed.  Note the conditional statement $T \mid H_0$ represents the assumption that the $X_i$ have mean $\mu = \mu_0$.

Comment: Wow! this answer really made me dig back through the Casella book and you are correct! I had actually never seen the t-distribution at all in my previous classes and thanks to you posting it I have finally been able to correct some of my misgivings. I see now that I was confusing the pivotal quantity with the t-distribution. And just to make certain the only way the pivotal quantity is a statistic is if we treat mu as a known constant? am I on the right track?

Comment: @user152810 Yes.  In fact, this speaks to how frequentist test statistics in general are constructed:  they employ a pivotal quantity which, under the assumption that the null hypothesis is true, would then have a distribution that does not depend on any unknown parameters—therefore, such a statistic can be calculated in practice and compared to a critical value representing in some sense the plausibility of such an assumption being true.  If the data generates a test statistic that is “very extreme” under this assumption, that furnishes evidence that the null is unlikely to be true.

Answer (score 1):

The t-distribution isn't a statistic. The t *estimator*, which is calculated using only the sample mean and standard deviation, *is* a statistic, and its distribution (under suitable assumptions and/or approximations) is the t-distribution with an appropriate number of degrees of freedom.

It's equivalent to the fact that the sample mean is (approximately) normally distributed, but the parameters of that distribution are based on (generally unknown) population parameters.

Comment: Thanks! Is the t estimator the same as the pivotal quantity that heropup has in his answer? If so, then this would mean the mu in the formula is ignored or treated as a known constant? As if mu were unknown the estimator would cease to be a statistic, correct? I think this is what is confusing me

Comment: Yes, when we use the t-statistic as part of a hypothesis test, we are comparing the sample against some assumed fixed value of $\mu$ - frequently, that assumed value is 0, which makes it "vanish" from the calculations (not ignored).

Answer (score 0):

The statistic is $\dfrac{\frac1n\sum_i x_i }{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_j(x_j-\frac1n\sum_i x_i)^2}}$ where everything comes from the sample data.

If the $\{X_i\}$ are an i.i.d. sample from a normal distribution with mean $0$ and any positive variance,  then this statistic has a Student $t$-distribution with $n−1$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Forgive me, but is the first formula what @ConMan below is referring to as the t-estimator? And would the t-estimator be in the form of the pivotal quantity that heropup has in his answer? Trying to understand where these formulas are coming from.

Comment: My expression is the same as heropup's pivotal quantity when $\mu=0$ and  heropup's test statistic when $\mu_0 = 0$, so can be used to test a null hypothesis of a zero mean.  But I was trying to address your desire for a statistic as a function of the sample data; the rest is just a relocation.  ConMan's description is slightly more general, saying that in many examples the  sample mean from other distributions has an approximate normal distribution, so a similar approach may work approximately there too.